# rspec mocking external api

Tags: testing, rspec, mocking, twilio

New to TDD here, d'oh!

Here's what I want to test ([ruby library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/ruby/install)), in brief:

```
 account = Twilio::RestAccount.new(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
    resp = account.request(
        "/#{API_VERSION}/Accounts/#{ACCOUNT_SID}/SMS/Messages",
        'POST',
        smsInfo
    )
```

And here's test code attempt:

```
describe Text do
  it "should call the Twilio API with credentials" do
    #pending "mocking api although not passed in.."
    t = mock(Twilio::RestAccount)
    twapi = mock("new twapi").should_receive(:request).and_return(Net::HTTPSuccess)
    t.stub(:new).and_return(twapi)

    Twilio::RestAccount.should_receive(:new)

    sms = Factory.create(:boring_sms)
    sms.send_sms
  end
end
```

which generates the error:  undefined method `request' for nil:NilClass

Am I taking the right approach? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Twilio and other external services, I also consider using VCR.  http://relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr

The upside is that you get it working once with manual testing, and it's basically verifying you don't mess anything up.  Downside is that any time you touch code tested by VCR, you often have to re-test everything manually that's tested by VCR.  Something else to consider.

Comment: Since this question was asked, I've become a big fan of VCR!

Answer (score 4):

Check out [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock). That's really what you want to use for something like this.

Answer (score 4):

You're stubbing new with 0 parameters, when you do this:

```
t.stub(:new).and_return(twapi)
```

But your test is:

```
Twilio::RestAccount.new(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
```

which is new with 2 params.

try:

```
t.should_receive(:new).once.with(any_args()).and_return(twapi)
```

and remove:

```
Twilio::RestAccount.should_receive(:new)
```